Cypress не показывает span с ошибкой, а в браузере этот span появляется
Проверяю валидацию ключа активации. В браузере, если длина ключа маленькая - выдает ошибку. В Cypress такая валидация не работает. Валидация с другими вариантами (не валидный ключ,
слишком длинный, не подходит по шаблону регулярного выражения) срабатывает без ошибок
cy.get('.input-key').type('ZZZ').should('has.value', 'ZZZ');
cy.get('.error-span').contains('Oops, entered incorrect characters');
cy.get('.button-send').should('be.disabled'); // disabled


надо использовать timeout
cy.get('.input-key', {timeout: 2000})

